# Removing chat history for a particular user from database

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently developing a web chat application using `SignleR` and `SQL server` this is my database schema so far

[image]

I've added an option where the user can `Clear Chat history` for a particular conversation , but I'm having trouble with the concept of clearing history for a particular user in wish case if user-1 hit clear history `all the messages of this conversation will not be displayed for user 1 but will still be seen for user-2`

How can I upgrade my database schema so I can make this functionality ?

Comment: Does `users.user_id` map to `messages.message_sender_id` and `message_receiver_id`?

Comment: yes @KevinHogg they do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a composite key table joining multiple users with with messages. I also think you are missing CONVERSATION table which will join multiple messages to the particular conversation.

The proposed scheme:

```
USERS          USER_THREADS      THREADS            MESSAGES
User_ID   ->      User_ID          
                 Thread_ID  ->  Thread_ID
                                Message_ID  ->      Message_ID
```

Now to clear a conversation for individual user you need to delete a record from the USER_THREADS table for that User_ID and Thread_ID.

The above scheme will also allow to carry conversation between more than two people as the THREAD can have many users by the below SELECT statement:

**Response to your comment:**

**Modification to the MESSAGE table:**

You don’t need a `MESSAGE_SENDER_ID` and `MESSAGE_RECIEVER_ID` as these information will be identified by `USER_THREADS` table. **EDIT:**
You should keep the `MESSAGE_SENDER_ID` in the `MESSAGE` table in order to identify the user who sent the message.

Let’s say when user logs in to your application will get all the conversation from the USER_THREADS table.

```
select  *
from          USER_THREADS as ut
inner join    THREADS as t on ut.Thread_ID = t.Thread_ID
inner join    MESSAGES  m on m.Message_ID = t.Message_ID
where         USER_THREADS.User_ID = 001
```

**SQL INSERT statement:**

When the user writes a message the application should insert the message body into MESSAGES table with an auto ID, That Message_ID will be then used by next insert statement to create new record in the THREADS table. You haven’t mentioned your DBMS but in MSSQL the SQL statement would look something like:

```
DECLARE @message_id int
insert into MESSAGES values (‘message body’)

set @message_id  = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -–an id of the newly inserted message

insert into THREADS values (@message_id, @thread_id)
```

**The SQL syntax for clearing the history for an individual user:**

```
delete from USER_THREADS where User_ID = 0000 AND Thread_ID = 0000
```

This will delete entire thread for that user

Comment: 1-is there any modifications for the messages table
2-if i want to insert a message lets say user1 sent a message to user2 what will be the insert statement

Comment: how can i select a conversation between user 1 and user 2

Comment: i saw the updates but in your Insert statement you didn't use the `User_thread` table ,if the user1 is starting a New conversation with User2 shouldn't I insert a row in that table ?

Comment: @Sora Yes, when the conversation doesn't exist, a new record in the `user_threads` table should be created.

Comment: other question , how can i deference between the sender and the receiver in your schema if i omitted the two columns in my messages table ?

Comment: @Sora Ah, yes for that purpose you still should keep these fields in that table. I've missed that requirement.

Comment: can you please provider the clear history sql statement as well please

Comment: the select statement you provide will return all the messages sent from user1 to all the users wish user1 is in chat with how can we modify this select statement to return only the messages between user1 and user2

Comment: @Sora The concept of the above solution is that all the participants will see the chat as soon the have loged in. You may want to implement a feature of private chat which will create a new thread onnly between two users. I think the above solution match the common scenarios of the chat application. If you want that messages will be exchanged between onnly to users then there is no need of the THREAD table as the whole conversation thread will consist on all messages between them (something like mobile text messaging).

Comment: @Sora In this case you need to only add USER-MESSAGES as an composite key to your oryginal scheme.